# SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When inserting a new product in my DB I am getting the following SQL error message:

**Form:**

[image: Create]

**Error SQL:**

[image: Sql]

I have been looking for information about it and this is a SQL error that can be fixed from Entity Framework but I am not getting good results

My models involved are the following...

**Producto.CS:**

```
public class Producto : IEntity
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} solo puede contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} solo puede contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Precio")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Imagen")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**Category.CS:**

```
 public class Category : IEntity
    {
        
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nombre Categoría")]
        [Required (ErrorMessage = "El campo categoría es obligatorio.")]
        [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "el campo {0} solo puede contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

**IEntity.CS:**

```
   public interface IEntity
   {
       int Id { get; set; }
            
   }
```

Attached my POST action of my product controller..

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductoViewModel view)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var path = string.Empty;

                if (view.ImageFile != null && view.ImageFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var file = $"{guid}.jpg";

                    path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\images\\Productos", file);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await view.ImageFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }

                    path = $"~/images/Productos/{file}";
                }

                //TRANSFORMO EL PRODUCTO PRODUCTOVIEWMODEL A PRODUCTO
                var producto = this.ToProducto(view, path);

                //USUARIO CREADOR
                producto.User = await userHelper.GetUserByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);

                //CATEGORIA DEL PRODUCTO
                producto.Category = await categoryRepository.GetByIdAsync(view.CategoryId);

                await productoRepository.CreateAsync(producto);

                //FALTA VALIDAR QUE DEVUELVE (TRUE OR FALSE)            
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(view);
        }

        private Producto ToProducto(ProductoViewModel view, string path)
        {
            return new Producto
            {
                Id = view.Id,
                ImageUrl = path,
                IsAvailabe = view.IsAvailabe,
                LastSale = view.LastSale,
                Name = view.Name,
                Description = view.Description,
                Price = view.Price,
                Stock = view.Stock,
                User = view.User,
                Category = view.Category
            };
        }
```

By following up with a breakpoint I make sure that I am sending a valid model

[image: Breakpoint]

I am occupying the repository pattern and my system crashes on the following line in my POST action

```
 await productoRepository.CreateAsync(producto);
```

I attach my **IProductoRepository.CS:**

```
  public interface IProductoRepository :  IGenericRepository<Producto>
    {

        IQueryable GetAllWithCategories();

        IQueryable GetAllWithUser();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetComboProductos();

    }
```

**GenericRepository.CS:**

```
  public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        private readonly DataContext context;

        public GenericRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            await this.context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await SaveAllAsync();
            return entity;
        }
    }
```

What's going on? Why can't I save a product with its respective category?

I have verified my various keys in my SQL engine

[image: Sql]

I am attaching my **DataContext.CS** as additional information:

```
     public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
        {
           
            public DbSet<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    
    
            #region Constructor
            public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
            {
    
            }
            #endregion

   //METODO QUE DESHABILITA EL BORRADO EN CASCADA 
        //Y ELIMINA LOS WARNING AL MIGRAR LA BASE DE DATOS
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //MANTISA DE 18 NUMEROS Y DOS DECIMALES
            modelBuilder.Entity<Producto>().Property(p => p.Price).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");

            //DESHABILITAR EL BORRADO EN CASCADA
            var cascadeFKs = modelBuilder.Model
                .G­etEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetForeignKeys())
                .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Casca­de);

            foreach (var fk in cascadeFKs)
            {
                fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restr­ict;
            }

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
    
        }
```

I have tried adding the following DataAnnotations to my classes in question:

1. [Key]
2. [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
3. [ForeignKey("....")]

Also deleting the Database I have tried everything again

I have also verified the Identity Specification value of my SQL

[image: IdentitySpecification]

I know this is a known ASP.NET Core bug, but how do I fix it in version 2.1? Am I forgetting something? Any help for me?

Comment: This is strange which should not happen. Do one thing, open your package manager console > add a new migration and update database. It might be possible that some changes were not committed to database that involved CategoryId.

Comment: I have migrated the DB without obtaining good results @noobprogrammer

Comment: Since it's an  `IDENTITY` column that's being set in the database backend, you **must NOT** set an explicit value for the `Id` column - don't include this line: `Id = view.Id,` - just leave `Id` unassigned - and your view shouldn't have an `Id` anyway......

Comment: I have commented on the line that you indicate, getting the same error, any other suggestions? @marc_s

Comment: Is there some other place where you set the `Id` explicitly? Just don't do that .....

Comment: @CristofherAmbiado somewhere you are setting the Id explicitly that's why the error. I see that IEntity is being inherited to your Category class, that "could" be one reason of error.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Category : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]   
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre Categoría")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "El campo categoría es obligatorio.")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "el campo {0} solo puede contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
}

public class Producto : IEntity
{    
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]   
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
  [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} ....")]
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
  [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} solo puede contener {1} 
  caracteres de largo.")]
  [Required]
  public string Description { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Precio")]
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
  public decimal Price { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Imagen")]
  public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

  public User User { get; set; }

  public int CategoryId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
  public Category Category { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, delete the database and include your suggestions, any other reference for me?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the same error, and not that the error now is on Producto ?

Comment: The error continues in the CATEGORIES table after adding these lines, I have also migrated the database before adding its lines ... what the hell is happening?

Comment: There is more missng, hold on, I'll update my answer ...

Comment: Fixed Producto-class as well, added foreign key close to bottom, and added id-stuff as well. Please note that I had to remove some of the message starting with "El campo {0}" in order to post the code. NOTE: I assume that you have a db-column called CategoryId in Product-table?

Comment: I have made the proposed changes and unfortunately I get the same error (also migrate the DB)

Comment: Please add code from OnModelCreating in your question if there is code there

Comment: I have updated my DataContext in which I have a method that adds a mantiza so that the products do not have prices above 2 decimal places and I also disable the cascade deletion for the completeness of the information, is that what you need? Have I added valuable information to search for the error?

Comment: Thanks. Can you try to comment out everything from //DESHABILITAR EL BORRADO EN CASCADA except for the last line? And please verify that identity specification is correct for both tables, unsure what table you are showing identity specification for.

Comment: I have really commented the lines, I don't have an additional code in my DataContext, will I have to put the DataAnnotations in my IEntity.CS? the error hasn't changed with all the changes made, it doesn't even give me a hint to follow it up!

Comment: Did you see this? "And please verify that identity specification is correct for both tables, unsure what table you are showing identity specification for." But i guess that is not the problem given the error message.

Comment: If you're still stuck, maybe it would be vice to bypass your custom repo and use context directly, context.Add() followed by context.SaveChangesAsync(). Just as part of the debug process of course.

Comment: I have already tried that having the same error, this does not let me advance

Comment: Then try to simplify things a little bit. Can you isolate Producto table by allowing it to have Category = null, and make sure Producto#Id = 0 when saving?